# Deploying Linux using Mono to deploy aspnet web/website application?

Tags: .net, linux, apache, mono

I have a C#/ASP.NET 4.0 framework application which works on windows with IIS. But recently I'm tempted to switch to Linux/Mono. It comes up with some questions:

Based on goggled i have found the option is using Mono cecil

so i downloaded and installed in windows

**in windows:**

1) Mono Migration Analyzer
2) Mono for Windows, Gtk#, and XSP

**in opensuse :**

zypper addrepo http://download.mono-project.com/download-stable/openSUSE_11.4 mono-stable
zypper refresh --repo mono-stable
zypper dist-upgrade --repo mono-stable

then i have given my dll to Mono Migration Analyzer for checking migration . finally it also succeed

now my problem is

1)How can i proceed after this step?

2)How can i make that web/website application to run on mono for conversion?

3)How can i make it to run with Apache tomcat server?

4)How can i make it to run the application in opensuse environment?

waiting for your valuable suggestions and comments

Comment: See this for some of the answers.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12895874/can-i-use-linux-mono-to-deploy-aspnet-web-application